# Weblogic : Using a combined keystore to listen to different SSL remote server response queues with multiple MDBs?

Tags: java, ssl, jms, weblogic, mq

I am setting up my application on Weblogic 12c where I need to setup different 2 MDBs which listen to 2 different remote server queues (based on MQ) – each with their own different SSL certificate keystores. I am using MDB + MQ Resource adapter for this.
I went ahead and combined the two keystores and set it up on my server by passing it as a JVM argument, but I am able to connect to only one of the remote server queue(lets call it #1), whereas getting security authentication MQ exception ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED') for the other(lets call it #2).

Talking more about the combined KS I created, they both use same certificates individually, with the exception that for #2's connections, it is required to have the following set for  its user authentiaction :
*OU=WMQCLIENT(m20238p)*
and in #1, our user is *OU=WMQCLIENT(m20238)*. *Notice the additional ‘p’ in #2?*

The aliases which contain the different values as described above are defined in my KS under different names. I suspect that it is only using one of these(#1), and not both, which is why I am getting an authentication error for #2's side.

I wish to dynamically provide my MDB listening to the #2 queue its keystore/alias values, is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that Java provides the cert not based on any cert label.  In the case of Java, when it connects to the queue manager the queue manager sends it's TLS SERVER HELLO message and this indicates all of the signers that the queue manager trusts.  The Java client will then look for a cert to present that is issued by a signer the queue manager trusts.  If the two certs direct issuers were different this may work for you, but in this case I would guess they are both issued by the same signer and Java probably just picks one, I have not seen this documented but I would guess the 1st cert.

Comment: In a normal MQ program you could specify a java system property (JSP) programmatically with something like `System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.keyStore', "/path/to/file.jks")`.  This likely won't help directly from weblogic using MDBs, but maybe you could create a program that runs in weblogic that itself creates an JMS async listener, in this way you could set the JSP before you you connect to the queue manager so point to two different jks files.

Comment: I also can't help but note that one has "p" and one does not.  My gut is that p=prod and the other is non-prod, I wouldn't recommend connecting to both prod and non-prod from the same app server instance, so another way to solve it is to connect from two different app server instances.

Comment: Abhishek, was this information helpful?  If so I'll post it in a answer, if not let me know if you have any further questions.